# clearInterval not working with setInterval

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a problem with the code below.
Basically im implementing a polling mechanism, but when it is supposed to stop polling it just continues to poll. Polling infinite.

Is there any other way to force it to stop?

The function SearchPoll is only called once.

```
function SearchPoll(){
    var i = setInterval(function () 
    { 
        var url = "Search.aspx?polling=true";        
        $.ajax( 
        { 
            url: url,
            success: function (data) 
            {     
                clearInterval(i); 
            }, 
            error: function () 
            { 
                clearInterval(i); 
            } 
        }); 
    }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: Did you verify you're actually running one of the code blocks which calls `clearInterval`?

Comment: Definitely do 2., `window.` shouldn't be written there explicitly, also for `clearInterval`. Style matters, too. :-)

Comment: Okay I found out that it works, but it just dont stop pooling instantly.. a couple of extra pools are done before it stops.. but why is that? Shouldnt it stop as soon as clearInterval is called? or is it some thread issue.. my application is multithreaded so maybe what I am seeing is just calls made from returning threads?

Comment: It's polling, not pooling. Pooling means to create a pool

Comment: What is this supposed to to? Send multiple requests until one of them comes back? How does this make any sense? Why are you sending multiple requests?

Comment: No the webapplication just sends 1 request and that is the searchword. The server application will create a thread which creates multiple threads that invoke a search on different websites. The poll is made because whenever one thread is done I want to show the result of that.. and continue to poll till all threads are done.

Comment: Yeah it was just the threads that confuessed me... it actually did stop once the threads had returned:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to kill all requests you need to work with the XMLHTTPRequest object returned from $.ajax.  Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Z6S/10/):

```
function SearchPool(){
    var xhrArray = [], 
        interval = setInterval(function () { 
            var url = "Search.aspx?polling=true";        
            xhrArray.push($.ajax({ 
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {     
                    for(var i = 0; i < xhrArray.length; i+= 1) {
                        xhrArray[i].abort();
                    }
                    clearInterval(interval); 
                }, 
                error: function () { 
                    clearInterval(interval);
                } 
            })); 
        }, 20);
}
SearchPool();
```

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle seems to work correctly...
http://jsfiddle.net/sramam/yZTAK/